# Prompting result is not good when giving context in JSON formatted raw data

Tags: prompt-design

I'm fetching mail conversations using an api that returns me data in this format

```
interface MailModel {
  "@odata.etag": string;
  id: string;
  createdDateTime: string;
  lastModifiedDateTime: string;
  changeKey: string;
  categories: string[];
  receivedDateTime: string;
  sentDateTime: string;
  hasAttachments: boolean;
  internetMessageId: string;
  subject: string;
  bodyPreview: string;
  importance: string;
  parentFolderId: string;
  conversationId: string;
  conversationIndex: string;
  isDeliveryReceiptRequested: boolean | null;
  isReadReceiptRequested: boolean;
  isRead: boolean;
  isDraft: boolean;
  webLink: string;
  inferenceClassification: string;
  body: {
    contentType: string;
    content: string;
  };
  sender: {
    emailAddress: {
      name: string;
      address: string;
    };
  };
  from: {
    emailAddress: {
      name: string;
      address: string;
    };
  };
  toRecipients: {
    emailAddress: {
      name: string;
      address: string;
    };
  }[];
  ccRecipients: {
    emailAddress: {
      name: string;
      address: string;
    };
  }[];
  bccRecipients: {
    emailAddress: {
      name: string;
      address: string;
    };
  }[];
  replyTo: {
    emailAddress: {
      name: string;
      address: string;
    };
  }[];
  flag: {
    flagStatus: string;
  };
}
```

Based on a drafted reply and the mail conversation history.
I would like that openAI  propose to me a professional reply

There's what I'm prompting

```
    const prompt = `The draft reply  \n ************* \n "${req.body.replyText }" \n**********\n  \n 
Conversation mail  : \n ###### ${JSON.stringify(cleanedMailExchange)} \n #####. \n \n 
Propose me a better reply in a professional business tone with use of corporate jargon. \n`;

{
  role: "system",
  content: `Improve my drafted reply to a mail conversation and make it look more professional reply . You should understand a mail conversation that i'll provide you. write a short reply`,
},
{ role: "user",
  content: prompt
}
```

So actually I'm not iterating over the json format data.

The issue is that OpenAI is not always improving the reply, but it's responding to it .

For example when I give " I'm not ok with you" as a reply to improve . Chatgpt respond with  " I'm sad to hear that you are not ok, ect " instead of writing :

> Hi [Recipient's Name],
>
> I wanted to express that I'm not okay with our recent interaction.
> Communication is important to me, and I believe discussing this can
> help us understand each other better. Can we find a time to talk about
> it?
>
> Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit prompt slightly ex.

"I have drafted a reply to an email conversation, but I need help refining it to sound more professional and incorporate appropriate corporate jargon. Here is my draft reply:

"DRAFT: [your draft]"

Based on the context of the email conversation below, please help me revise my draft to create a polished and professional response.

Email Conversation Context:
${JSON.stringify(cleanedMailExchange)}

Please provide a revised version of my draft that maintains the intended message but enhances the tone, clarity, and formality appropriate for a business setting."

I think that can help.

Comment: Realy nice prompt. thanks !